# How detect when ajax cart is refreshed [PRESTASHOP 1.7]

Tags: prestashop, cart, prestashop-1.7

I have problem with refreshing cart. When cart page is loading, activated is javascipt code that modify html, but when somoething in cart is updated (quantity or sth is  deleted) html is refreshed and my changes disapear, so how i can detect when cart refreshing is done ?
I tried use event "cartUpdate", but it was triggered before html refresh.
I attach screen with requests that are triggered when sth in cart is updated

[SCREEN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFJLL.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a module and implement actionBeforeAjaxDie hook.